# How to resize Phaser's Canvas without changing the pixel value?

Tags: javascript, css, html, phaser-framework

I`m looking for a way to sort of zoom in/zoom out on my Phaser app depending on the screen size while keeping the ratio (and not altering the canvas size pixelwise as shown on the sketch), I tried so many snippets but everybody is sort of looking for something else, this is what I'm looking for(also, the code below where the screen gets "full screened" works on desktop but not on mobile):

[image]

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(1100,600, Phaser.Canvas,"gameDiv");

var mainState = {

    init: function () {

  game.renderer.renderSession.roundPixels = true;

  game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

  game.physics.arcade.gravity.y = 800;

  game.physics.arcade.gravity.x = -10850;

    },
 preload: function(){

        //Loads background imagery
  game.load.image(`background`, "assets/background_1877_600.png");



 },
 create: function(){
        
         // function to scale up the game to full screen
       // function to scale up the game to full screen
        game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
        game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
        
        
        game.scale.fullScreenScaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;

        game.input.onDown.add(gofull, this);

        function gofull() {

            if (game.scale.isFullScreen)
            {
                //game.scale.stopFullScreen();
            }
            else
            {
                game.scale.startFullScreen(true);
            }

        }


  background = game.add.tileSprite(0,0,1877,600,`background`);
  
 },
 update: function(){
  background.tilePosition.x -= 0.25;
  
 }
}

game.state.add(`mainState`,mainState);
game.state.start(`mainState`);
```

```html
<html>

 <head>
  <title>Agame</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="phaser.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <style>
            html, body{
                 overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
 </head>

 <body>
       
 </body>

</html>
```

If you have any idea on how I could achieve this, let me know

Comment: Have you tried `Game(window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio, window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio, Phaser.Canvas, 'gameDiv')`?

Comment: I want to avoid that so I`ll have to adjust the game for that and more problems will rise like DPR differences from device to device, I was looking to achieve the same effect as in turning the game to full screen, you just zoom in

Comment: Allow me to suggest that you add that detail to your problem description.  It will encourage your readers to think in a different direction.

Comment: Absolutely, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you do something like this at the start.

```
var x = 1100;
    var y = 600;

// window.onresize = function(event) {

// }

var w = window.screen.width;

    if(w > 900){
        //ok
    }
    else if(w > 600){
        x = 600;
        y = 400;
    }
    else {
        x = 300;
        y = 100;
    }

var game = new Phaser.Game(x,y, Phaser.Canvas,"gameDiv");
```

This will only work when you load a new device but you can add screen change event to resize while screen change its up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best idea would be like:

```
    html, body{
width: 100vw;
width: 100%; /*FallBack Width */
height: 100vh;
height: 100%; /*Same Here*/
}
.required-element{
font-size: 10vh; /*Or required */
}
/*And this will change according to the screen size
But, be sure add viewport to the html meta tag. */
```